# Getx Flutter dependency injection through binding

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to use binding class to inject dependecies into my flutters application but for some reason its not working as i expected

binding class

```
class LibraryHomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(LibraryHomeController(), tag: 'home');
  }
}
```

controller class

```
class LibraryHomeController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('initilizing');
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    print('Controller ready');
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    print('Controller closing');
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

home

```
class LibraryHome extends StatelessWidget {
  LibraryHome({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;
  final libraryHomeBinding = Get.find(tag: 'home');
...
}
```

main

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: lightTheme,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/home',
          page: () => LibraryHome(title: 'Library'),
          binding: LibraryHomeBinding(),
        )
      ],
      initialRoute: '/home',
    );
  }
}
```

i am getting this error

""dynamic" not found. You need to call "Get.put(dynamic())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>dynamic())""

Answer (score 1):

on the binding class i think using extends is not quite right but use instead  `with/implements`

```
class LibraryHomeBinding with Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() { 
   /// use lazy put
    Get.lazyPut(LibraryHomeController(),fenix: true,tag: 'home');
  }
}
```

then on the controller do it like this

```
class LibraryHomeController extends GetxController {
  final findBind = Get.find<LibraryHomeController>( tag: "home");
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('initilizing');
    super.onInit();
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when calling the `Get.find()` you specified the tag, but you didn't specify the type, `Getx` use the type and tag to generate a consistent key to get what you want so you need to do this :

```
  final libraryHomeBinding = Get.find<LibraryHomeController>(tag: 'home');
```

or

```
  final LibraryHomeController libraryHomeBinding = Get.find(tag: 'home');
```

now it will find it.